# Error during Django test

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'm trying to run a test in Django and I keep getting this error when Django tries to create the test DB.

`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "userprofile_user" does not exist`

Here is my UserProfile model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=140, null=True)
    age_range_min = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    age_range_max = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    locale = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'Profile of user: %s' % self.user.email
```

Here is the full stack trace:

```
Destroying old test database 'default'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/chad/.virtualenvs/site/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/chad/.virtualenvs/site/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 346, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/chad/.virtualenvs/site/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 30, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
  File "/Users/chad/.virtualenvs/site/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 394, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/chad/.virtualenvs/site/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 74, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/chad/.virtualenvs/site/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 445, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/chad/.virtualenvs/site/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 90, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
  File "/Users/chad/.virtualenvs/site/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 210, in run_tests
    old_config = self.setup_databases()
  File "/Users/chad/.virtualenvs/site/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 166, in setup_databases
    **kwargs
  File "/Users/chad/.virtualenvs/site/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 370, in setup_databases
    serialize=connection.settings_dict.get("TEST", {}).get("SERIALIZE", True),
  File "/Users/chad/.virtualenvs/site/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 368, in create_test_db
    test_flush=not keepdb,
  File "/Users/chad/.virtualenvs/site/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 120, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/Users/chad/.virtualenvs/site/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 445, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/chad/.virtualenvs/site/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 179, in handle
    created_models = self.sync_apps(connection, executor.loader.unmigrated_apps)
  File "/Users/chad/.virtualenvs/site/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 318, in sync_apps
    cursor.execute(statement)
  File "/Users/chad/.virtualenvs/site/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/chad/.virtualenvs/site/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 98, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/chad/.virtualenvs/site/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "userprofile_user" does not exist
```

Comment: What version of django are you using? It looks like the old style approach with a separate model for the user and the profile.  With recent versions of django it's easy to create a single customer user model?

Comment: I'm using Django 1.8

Comment: Also, when I run `makemigrations` it reports `No changes detected`

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is a problem with your migrations, try to add this to your settings in order to by pass them during tests:

```
class DisableMigrations(object):

    def __contains__(self, item):
        return True

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return "notmigrations"


TESTS_IN_PROGRESS = False
if 'test' in sys.argv[1:]:
    logging.disable(logging.CRITICAL)
    PASSWORD_HASHERS = (
        'django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5PasswordHasher',
    )
    DEBUG = False
    TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False
    TESTS_IN_PROGRESS = True
    MIGRATION_MODULES = DisableMigrations()
```

Comment: Thank you that worked.  I had to fix some indentation on the class methods though.  I guess I need to research how to fix my migration now...

Comment: Glad to hear that, I'd appreciate an up vote from you ;-)

Comment: The line `MIGRATION_MODULES = DisableMigrations()` needs to be indented as well.